# Insert the output of shell command into emacs buffer

Tags: emacs

I want to set a key binding to insert the date into the buffer.  I have written the following lisp in my `.emacs` file.  Using `date` as an example:

```
;;put the date                                                                  
(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-c C-d")
 (shell-command "date" (current-buffer))
)
```

The key binding works okay when I use other commands like `'next-line`, but `shell-command` will put it into the `*scratch*` buffer when the .emacs is read and leaves it at that.

Maybe I need to use `shell-command-on-region`.

Comment: The `(current-buffer)` gets evaluated when your `.emacs` runs.  You want to use `(shell-command "date" t)` to have it insert in the buffer which is current when you invoke the command, or encapsulate it in a `defun`, so that it gets evaluated when you execute the function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A friend of mine at work helped me.

```
(defun put-the-date ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (shell-command-to-string "date")))

(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-c C-d")
 'put-the-date
 )
```

Comment: There is no need to call the shell for something that can be obtained within emacs:

(insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

Comment: Thank you, but I was just using it as an example of a shell script that outputs some kind of string... Could have been "echo hi" or "ls" really...

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-d") (lambda () (interactive) (insert (shell-command-to-string "date"))))` uses an anonymous function and is more succint.

Comment: for the evil-mode people out there: `(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC f d") (lambda () (interactive) (insert (shell-command-to-string "date +%F_%T"))))`

Comment: @sjas I actually prefer having a separate command and keybinding despite the small extra length. 1) This is the pattern the built-in functions and most packages use. 2) Browsing the keymap (`C-h m` or similar) will show a useful overview, rather than an anonymous function. 3) You can find the new command when browsing available functions, e.g. when using tab completion under `M-x`.

Answer (score 103):

For the general case of inserting any output of a shell command to the current buffer, you can use the in-built keyboard chords:

```
C-u M-! <shell-command>
```

which runs the same `shell-command` function, and also inserts the output back at the point in the current buffer.

The entire key-stroke itself can be saved as a macro (and perhaps assigned to a shortcut) for easier invocation of common shell commands.

Comment: Awesome, though some situations are best served by deleting the newline at the end (e.g. in ERC, rcirc, etc.) in which case go to the end of the line/output (C-e) and then to delete the newline hidden char: C-d  (this addition nicked from Mickery Petersen's Mastering Emacs site).